# Using a custom lib path

Tags: linux, privileges

I'm trying to build Android on a remote trough ssh. However, I was presented with the problem:

> prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: /lib32/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by prebuilt/linux-x86/toolchain/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.x/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc)

After looking at the *libc.so.6* I saw that it was actually 2.9.

I don't however have administrative privileges on the server. So I tried copying my libc-2.11.1.so to a folder in my home dir, say `/home/users/myuser/lib/`, made a symbolic link so that /home/users/myuser/lib/libc.so.6 would point to the actual so and added the `lib` folder to my `PATH`.

However it didn't make any difference.

Doing `ldd` on the mentioned elf file:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf77a6000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf762d000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77a7000)
```

So it looks like the required library has a fixed path.

Does anyone know how I could make it link to `/home/users/myusers/lib/libc.so.6` instead of `/lib32/libc.so.6/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/lib/
```

Just in case one might also add:

```
export LD_PATH=~/lib/
export LIBPATH=~/lib/
```